# Nginx disable password protection for single dir

Tags: nginx

I have all directories protected with a password as below.

I have one dir `./opendir` (or: `/var/www/opendir`) and I would like it to be open. (not restricted)

How can I do this?

```
server {
        listen       80;

        root /var/www/;
        index index.php;

        server_name localhost;

        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/.htpasswd;

        location / {
        ........... ETC ...........
```

Comment: @YuriPrezument this is not 100% the same question, it is the question in reverse :-)

Comment: Doesn’t both ask how to allow only one directory...?

Answer (score 1):

```
location ^~ /myurl/ {
            auth_basic off;
            autoindex on;
   }
```